# Focus-follows-mouse for Google Chrome on macOS?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, mouse, window-focus

I am seeking focus-follows-mouse behavior for Google Chrome windows on macOS. The desired behavior is that if there are two browser windows, occupying the left and right halves of the screen, then moving the mouse from the left half of the screen to the right half of the screen would change focus from the left browser window to the right.

I have tried enabling focus-follows-mouse behavior more generally. Following the answers linked below, I have been able to enable this behavior for Terminal and iTerm windows as well as for X11 applications. Furthermore I have seen that the Amethyst window manager supports this behavior, although I do not wish to replace the default window manager with a tiling window manager for various reasons. Lastly, the app Zooom/2 has been recommend in various answers linked to below, although this app now appears to be defunct and the links give 404 errors.

---

Relevant links:

- [Zooom/2 recommendation](https://superuser.com/questions/27306/focus-follows-mouse-or-sloppy-focus-on-mac-os-x)
- [Old FFM question from ask different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98310/focus-follows-mouse-plus-auto-raise-on-mac-os-x)
- [Other](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/5/how-can-i-make-focus-follow-the-mouse-cursor) [related](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/87655/how-do-i-make-os-x-auto-focus-on-the-window-in-the-screen-the-mouse-moves-into?rq=1) [questions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168831/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-mouse-to-automatically-focus-on-an-active-window?rq=1) [from](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/222253/stop-google-chrome-from-stealing-focus-on-opening?rq=1) ask different
- I asked similar questions on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43336156/focus-follows-mouse-for-google-chrome-on-macos) and [ask different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/280307/focus-follows-mouse-and-autoraise-for-chrome-windows) with no answers

Comment: See this meta discussion, from 4 years ago. [How do I ask a question that may require recommending software?](//meta.superuser.com/q/5372)

Comment: Thank you for linking me to there, as a new member of this community I had no clue such a page existed. I believe my question is essentially of the form recommended therein, although I can rephrase it as being more "problem-based" if that is what is desired.

Comment: Yes, you can [edit] to remove for example "Is there an extension for" and phrase the question more along the lines "This is the behaviour I want" ..."How can I do this". The edit will put the question in the reopen queue.

Comment: The question has been edited to follow the guidelines you linked to.

Comment: Excellent. I've reopened the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus follows mouse is possible in macOS, Mojave in my case, using [chunkwm](https://koekeishiya.github.io/chunkwm/docs/source.html). 
 See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55936326/4637974) Stack Overflow response for a "no autoraise" solution.  Autoraise is activated by leaving

```sh
chunkc set ffm_disable_autoraise         0
```

in `~/.chunkwmrc`.

Answer (score 0):

See this similar question - which is not specific to chrome but for macOS in general: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67258537/focus-follows-mouse-on-macos